# PHP script that was working suddenly stops working and sarts giving various errors

Tags: php, xampp

I have developed a web app that was running just fine. I have used PDO to accessing MySql.

But after upgrading to new version of Xampp now it is giving a variety of errors like for example: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\web2print\includes\database-abstract.php on line 43

Originally I was using Xampp 1.8.1 and I have upgraded to version 5.6.3.

What must be the problem?

Comment: show you code to get better answer

Comment: There are many potential pitfalls if you upgrade across PHP versions, especially if your old version was <= PHP 5.3. You must post the offending code from your `abstract.php` file to begin sorting it out.

Comment: without the actual code/line we can't really determine the problem and find a solution. As said by abdulla, the code would be helpfull.

Comment: Hard to say without the code. But whatever variable you are assigning to initialize PDO is returning a string (probably error message) and query() function will not execute. Most likely an outdated use of PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

I have found the solution to my problem.

Let me try and explain as to what I have done to solve it:

I was including all related PHP modules using statement like this:

```
require_once "includes\database-abstract.php";
```

After changing all such statements to:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."database-abstract.php";
```

Solved the problem!

So there was not problem in the **database-abstract.php** file code as it was working perfectly for a year in older version of Xampp. The actual problems started occurring after upgrading Xampp to a newer version.

Hope this will help someone.

Yogi Yang